# Use Npgsql 3 with C# in Visual Studio 2010 net framework 4

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have a c# visual studio 2010 desktop application. And I use the [npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/) 2.2.7. With this npgsql version, when I have an error, for example a duplicated primary key, my app is not responding and the error is not appearing to the user.

But in Visual Studio 2015 with npgsql 3.0.3 in a test app, the npgsql works fine and the error appears as expected.

So, I try to install npgsql 3.0,5 in Visual Studio 2010, but I got this error:

> Install-Package : No se encuentra la versión '3.0.5' del paquete 'Npgsql'.

The npgsql 3 works only with .netframework 4.5, and my app uses net framework 4. Any idea about how to solve this problem? I need use npgsql 3 in my Visual Studio 2010 app?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a .NET 4.0 app use a .NET 4.5 library (Npgsql). It might be possible to analyze the bug in 2.2.7 and fix it, but the 2.x line isn't receiving much attention because it's old, so there's not much chance of that. Note that .NET 4.0 has reached it's end of life, consider moving forward to 4.5/4.6...

Answer (score 0):

> Support for .NET 2.0, .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 has been dropped - you will have to upgrade to .NET 4.5 to use Npgsql 3.0. We’ll continue to do bugfixes on the 2.2 branch for a while on a best-effort basis.

http://www.npgsql.org/doc/migration-3.0.html

Either target .NET 4.5 in your application, [submit a bug report to the ngpgsql maintainers](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues) or try downgrading to an [earlier version of ngpgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/) to see if this behaviour is replicated in those versions.

Comment: It is also worth noting that .NET 4 is no longer supported by Microsoft http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1.aspx